# Failing to install Ubuntu - Read-only filesystem

Tags: drivers, system-installation, acer, aspire

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 (same with previous 15.10) on a Acer Aspire E1-510. I received the pc from a friend of mine, not used to Linux, that already failed the installation, then deleting the previous Windows version. I don't care about dual boot, only getting Ubuntu there.

I created a Usb stick with the Startup disk creator. Loaded into the pc, clicked "Install Ubuntu". The installation ran fine, selected to delete the previous version of Ubuntu, loaded wifi, all seemed fine.
Got to file copy, run until "Copy file 55 of 55" and then black screen, lot of errors and stop. It appeared a little window on a black screen reporting a system error and then nothing.

Tried to load then live, but it just visualized the console and then the same error. I can still load terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1, thought.

Loading without usb still takes to the same problem.
I selected the option to download driver from the net.

Is this a graphic driver problem? Please help me, I'm clueless.

EDIT: Tried to live with Ubuntu 16.04. Opens to a black screen that remains for more than ten minutes. Still able to open terminals with Ctrl+Alt+Fn, and log-in with user Ubuntu.
I also tried Kubuntu 16.04 (I had that already downloaded). It opened live with no problem, but the installation wizard stopped after settings (more or less same point it stopped for Ubuntu when I direct installed) with "[Errno 30] Read only disk".

EDIT: Tried intalling Ubuntu (no live). Crashed the installation after system and program installation with:

```
error setting ownership of './lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/kernel/divers/input/input-polldev.ko': Read-only file system
```

[image: img]

Now the mouse is stuck. No idea of what to do.

Rebooting now (not from usb) take me again to a grub> prompt.
I think it's like he cannot properly install the grub bootloader... but I know almost nothing of that.

Comment: 15.10 is no longer supported. Use the latest stable version 16.04 LTS or the older 14.04 LTS instead.

Comment: @ByteCommander The problem remais on version 16.04 with almost no changes

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, I voted to reopen it. However, could you please add e.g. a photo of the error messages you see? It's important for us to know the exact messages to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't took a photo of the kubuntu error. Now I'm trying the direct install of Ubuntu and It seem to run strangerly fine... I'll update at soon at possible

Comment: The installation is stuck with the error reported